# PHP not able to access POST values

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a HTML login form that is processed and displayed to the user by PHP if they are not logged in. This form is set to POST to /user.php which in turn accesses my authentication class, and either creates a session and returns true or false and does not log the user in.

My problem is that whatever I try, the HTML form simply will not POST values to the PHP processing part.

This is my current source code:

Log in form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- BEGIN ifLogInError -->
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <p>Either your username or password was incorrect. Please try again. <a href="" class="alert-link">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END ifLogInError -->
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{ROOT}/user.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="" placeholder="Your username">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="" placeholder="Your password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign in" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

User.php (as it currently stands):

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo "</pre>";
phpinfo();
```

Both var_dumps return the following, suggesting the form is not POSTing:

```
array(0) {
}
string(0) ""
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have not used name attributes on your input tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given your `<input>`s a `name` attribute.

Comment: I am such a moron. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Needs  `<input name="myname">`
Then in the output file put `$_POST['myname']`